# Не работает класс carousel-fade Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, bootstrap4

Хотел добавить эффект растворения слайдов. В документации нашел класс carousel-fade. Но почему-то не хочет работать и слайды перелистываются по умолчанию. 
В чем может быть проблема?

```
 <div class="container slider">
  <div id="slider" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#slider" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#slider" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="img/411-1062x501-grayscale.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/1062/501?grayscale" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#slider" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#slider" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: работает же....

Comment: у меня не срабатывает( Происходит перелистывание по умолчанию, без растворения слайдов